# Do we still need drawable folder in Android Resources if already have drawable - hpi, mdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, drawable

[image: Image Sample]

What size of image should I put into drawable folder which is not drawable - ldpi, hpi, mdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi, xxxhdpi? Or do I still need the drawable folder?

Comment: Yes. That drawable folder is used for xml files. like custom backgrounds, shapes, etc

Comment: Then may I know whats the size and dpi of image should i use in that drawable folder? @Deepakkaku

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/HT4YlyONGpnN

Comment: We don't put actual images in drawable folder

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, we still need **drawable** folder. All the folders you mentioned help android app to store different density images according to their density but when you access them into your app system will select the appropriate image based on the **screen's API**.

[image]You could also follow documentation for further details [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Comment: Then may I know whats the size and dpi of image should i use in that drawable folder? https://www.screencast.com/t/HT4YlyONGpnN  @Prashant

Comment: @KharFaiMak Good question, anything else that insn't dpi related still has to go into /res/drawabel folder.